# This story and also this kind of stories(is/are) usually ... Which one is correct? Why?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? Why?

> 1. This story and also this kind of stories **are** usually about money & marriage.
> 2. This story and also this kind of stories **is** usually about money & marriage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that neither is correct.

If you use **this kind** you need to retain the singular **of story**
in the same way that you would speak of **this kind of house**.

Alternatively, you can say **these kinds of stories**.

This construction takes the plural because the subject is plural. It is both **this story** and **these kinds of stories**:

> This story and also these kinds of stories are usually about money & marriage

A similar example, that makes things clearer, would be:

> The mayor and the group of councillors supporting him are wrong.

You will find helpful examples and explanations of Subject-Verb Agreement at a number of sites such as:

https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp
https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/subjectverbagreement

Comment: +1 but personal vote to always keep it singular. 'These kinds of plurals' always lead[s] ;) the reader down strange pathways. 'This kind of singular' is always easier to follow.

Comment: Far better would be *this story* ***and those of its kind*** *are usually about money and marriage.* The version you gave is correct but very awkward. The use of **also** needs to be pointed out as another problem.